# Is it fine to target .wat instead of .wasm and use wat2wasm?

Tags: exceptions, webassembly

IIRC the WebAssembly text format (.wat) is not able to express everything .wasm can, such as <s>binary</s> (custom) sections. I'm not sure about the current state of WebAssembly text and binary formats now though.

I asked here recently about how I could add source locations (including the full call stack) to thrown exceptions in C++ and got [this answer](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/1738/606) suggesting the `#line` directive (which can be useful in my case) and the use of `libunwind` to collect the call stack.

I was thinking of researching on the WebAssembly target for avoiding possible name clash and reserved keywords
issues and also because I'm not experienced with C++.

I'm wondering if it's feasible to target .wat since writing the binary manually requires more work. Did any language do this in practice? I know Lobster targets the binary format (.wasm), but I use another language for my type checker, C#, and Lobster's writer is written in C++, so it may be problematic to port it.

---

It looks like C# does have a library for writing .wasm: https://github.com/RyanLamansky/dotnet-webassembly

Comment: Tangential to the question, but if you target wasm, you might face [this issue](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/1064/160).

Comment: Are either of the existing answers acceptable, or does a new answer need to be written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think yes, the compiler should produce `.wat` format.

My Valkyrie language now uses the `.wat` format, and a long time ago it directly output `.wasm`.

Next I will explain the reasons for this change, I hope it will be helpful to you.

---

As preparatory knowledge, first introduce some core libraries and concepts I use
​

- [wasm-encoder](https://crates.io/crates/wasm-encoder): The widely used wasm linker, which produces `.wasm`
- [wast-encoder](https://github.com/nyar-vm/nyar-vm/tree/644b0a0321bdab74262e49ce455565b05dee41c2/projects/wast-encoder): The new linker I implemented, output is `.wat`
- [wasmparser](https://crates.io/crates/wasmparser): The widely used wasm parser and validator, supporting both text and binary.
- [wasm-opt](https://crates.io/crates/wasm-opt): Widely used optimizer, but does not support the latest wit components.

A long time ago I used `wasm-encoder` to directly encode my types, and `wasm-opt` to optimize the binary, and everything was great.

Until the introduction of wit and gc, various tool chains were unable to parse the gc instructions and wit definitions emitted by wasm-encoder. Only the chrome browser could execute the binary I output, but it was very difficult to debug.

This has been going on for a long time and will continue to be for a long time. My toolchain is paralyzed.

In this context I developed `wast-encoder`, which handles the linking process and finally outputs `.wat`. This is essentially a linker, not an encoder.

In the wit component, the wasm modules need to be instantiated in a specific order, and each newly defined type must reference an already defined type. This is beyond the scope of a simple coder.

Another reason is that the instructions issued by the encoder erase the information in the source language. Even if chrome tells me which line wasm reports an error, I don't know what went wrong.

`wasm-encoder` emits code similar to this (decompiled)

```
(component
  (import "wasi:io/error@0.2.0" (instance (;1;) (type 1)))
  (alias export 1 "error" (type (;2;)))
  (type (;3;)
    (instance
      (export (;0;) "output-stream" (type (sub resource)))
      (alias outer 1 2 (type (;1;)))
      (export (;2;) "error" (type (eq 1)))
      (type (;3;) (own 2))
      (type (;4;) (variant (case "last-operation-failed" 3) (case "closed")))
      (export (;5;) "stream-error" (type (eq 4)))
      (type (;6;) (borrow 0))
      (type (;7;) (list u8))
      (type (;8;) (result (error 5)))
      (type (;9;) (func (param "self" 6) (param "contents" 7) (result 8)))
      (export (;0;) "[method]output-stream.blocking-write-and-flush" (func (type 9)))
    )
  )
  (import "wasi:io/streams@0.2.0" (instance (;2;) (type 3)))
  (alias export 2 "output-stream" (type (;4;)))
  (core instance (;4;)
    (export "get-stdin" (func 2))
  )
  (alias export 5 "get-stdout" (func (;5;)))
)
```

`wast-encoder` emits more understandable code, although this is longer.

```
(component $Root
    (import "wasi:io/error@0.2.0" (instance $wasi:io/error@0.2.0
        ;; class std::io::Error
        (export "error" (type (sub resource)))
    ))
    (alias export $wasi:io/error@0.2.0 "error" (type $io-error))

    ;; variant std::io::StreamError
    (type $stream-error (variant
    (case "last-operation-failed" (own $io-error))
        (case "closed")
    ))

    (import "wasi:io/streams@0.2.0" (instance $wasi:io/streams@0.2.0
    (export $output-stream "output-stream" (type (sub resource)))

        (alias outer $Root $io-error (type $io-error))
    (export $stream-error0 "stream-error" (type (eq $stream-error)))
    (export $stream-error1 "alias0" (type (eq $stream-error)))

        (export "[method]output-stream.blocking-write-and-flush"
            ;; class std::io::OutputStream
            ;; method blocking-write-and-flush(self) -> Result<(), std::io::Error>
            (func (param "self" (borrow $output-stream)) (param "contents" (list u8)) (result (result (error $stream-error0))))
        )
    ))
    (alias export $wasi:io/streams@0.2.0 "output-stream" (type $output-stream))
    (alias export $wasi:io/streams@0.2.0 "alias0" (type $output-stream0))

    (import "wasi:cli/stdout@0.2.0" (instance $wasi:cli/stdout@0.2.0
    (alias outer $Root $output-stream (type $output-stream))
        (export "get-stdout"
            ;; class std::io::OutputStream
            ;; static stdout() -> Self
            (func (result (own $output-stream)))
        )
    ))
)
```

The size issue is not very important. Although `wasm-opt` does not currently support `gc` and `wit`, compact binaries will be obtained in the future.

In contrast, text with source language information and structure is more helpful for debugging.

---

Finally, focus your scenario in question.

There is currently no specification standard that can emit raw stack information. I know that LLDB can add some custom instructions, and chrome can recognize and jump directly, but this is non-standard, the tool chain support is limited, and the future is uncertain.

I have a proposal for tools to recognize such information (this is legal wasm, even now).
​

```
(func $always-one
    (@name "function-name-in-source-language")
    (@file "user/language/source.vk")
    (@line 12)
    (@column 4)
    (result i32) 
    (i32.const 0)
)
```

In any case, I hope to use the solution within the wasm standard, rather than the solution customized by various tools.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the main compiler for my programming language, the [AEC-to-WebAssembly compiler](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/AECforWebAssembly.git), does output `.wat` and use `wat2wasm`. My programming language doesn't have exceptions, though, nor would I know how to implement them.